# How does python know what function to call when function name is same as a built-in one

Tags: python

I have two code blocks in two separate python files.

file1.py:

```
import numpy as np

def min(a):
    print('Self defined function')
    return np.amin(a)

a = [2,3,4]
print(min(a))
```

I run this and it returned:

Self defined function

2

file2.py:

```
a = [2,3,4]
print(min(a))
```

I run this and it returned:

2

My question is, how does python know the self defined function should be called, even if it has the same name as the built-in function in python?

Is it a good practice to use the same function name?

Comment: No, its not a good practice! Your function min has overwritten* the built-in min function.

Comment: Your self defined function will just override the built-in one, so you should avoid using these built-in function names. Override also apply when you use them as variable like `min = 0`, error will be raised when you run the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is handled by namespaces.

When you start-up python, there are multiple built-in names, such as `min` and `max`, these belong to the **built-in** namespace.

Right after it is started up, it starts executing the main program (the script that you chose, or the lines that you feed through the terminal) in a newly created **global** namespace, in this main program, you create variables using statements, like `max = 2`. When you execute `max = 2` in the main program, python will register that `max` is now `2` in the **global namespace**.

So, the next time you reference `max`, python will look first in the global namespace to check if there `max` is defined, then it will return `2`. But if `max` wasn't defined in this namespace (e.g. you did not run `max = 2`), then it would try further and look in the **built-in namespace**, in which case it would find the `max` built-in function. If it doesn't find anything, a `NameError` will be raised.

Here's an example:

```
Python 3.9.7 (default, Sep 16 2021, 08:50:36)
[Clang 10.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> max = 32
>>> max
32
>>> del max
>>> max(32, 64)
64
>>>
```

Keep in mind that replacing names from the built-in namespace like you did can make the code confusing, specially as another developer (maybe even yourself from the future) reads the code and forgets that `max` has been redefined, for example. Not only that, but the function itself would not be easy to call. So try appending something like `_` to create `_max`, or something like `max_value`, that should make your code easier to read.

You can find more information about namespaces (and scopes) [here](https://realpython.com/python-namespaces-scope).

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with how Python handles scopes. There's a lot to say with regard to scopes, but it essentially boils down Python prioritizing what you've created over what's already built-in. If you want to understand it at a deeper level, read this article: https://realpython.com/python-scope-legb-rule

As for your second question: try to avoid name collisions with built-in keywords, functions or modules, as much as possible. (Never say never and all that... but those are extreme cases.) If you think you can't find a better name or a shortened version, append an underscore to the name. (e.g. `min()` is built-in while `min_()` is your function. But as I said, try to avoid doing this.)